# Issues with creating a Neural Network & Traning

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, image-classification

I've been stuck with an issue of a model not being able to be trained for some time now, and I was hoping to get some help on it. Here is part of the code

```
link = "https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/efficientnet_v2_imagenet1k_b0/feature_vector/2"
input_layer = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(224, 224, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name="input", trainable=False)
feature_extractor = hub.KerasLayer(link, trainable=False)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    input_layer,
    feature_extractor,
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(data_info.features['label'].num_classes, activation="softmax")
])
```

And here is the error I'm getting:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[64], line 7
      4 input_layer = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(224, 224, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name="input")
      5 feature_extractor = hub.KerasLayer(link, trainable=False)
----> 7 model = tf.keras.Sequential([
      8     input_layer,
      9     feature_extractor,
     10     tf.keras.layers.Dense(data_info.features['label'].num_classes, activation="softmax")
     11 ])
     13 model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
     14 model.summary()

File c:\Users\steel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\trackable\base.py:204, in no_automatic_dependency_tracking.<locals>._method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    202 self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    203 try:
--> 204   result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    205 finally:
    206   self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

File c:\Users\steel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
...


Call arguments received by layer "keras_layer_28" (type KerasLayer):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), dtype=float32)
  • training=None
```

I've tried a number of different things like adding or removing the input layer and changing some of the parameters in that layer, but I'm not having luck. I wonder if it's because of the network I've extracted, but wanted to get some confirmation on that first because I'm not 100% sure how to determine if that's the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The error you're encountering seems to stem from the hub.KerasLayer function call. It appears that the function is expecting additional arguments related to training, but they are not provided.

try the code below

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub

link = "https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/efficientnet_v2_imagenet1k_b0/feature_vector/2"
feature_extractor = hub.KerasLayer(link, trainable=False)

# Define your input layer separately
input_layer = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(224, 224, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name="input")

# Pass the input through the feature extractor
features = feature_extractor(input_layer)

# Define the output layer
output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation="softmax")(features)

# Create the model
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])

# Print the model summary
model.summary()
```

Comment: Just tried this out and it ended up working! Thanks for the feedback. Just for the sake of learning, would you mind providing an explanation as to why adding the output layer was needed?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://www.kaggle.com/models/google/efficientnet-v2/frameworks/tensorFlow2/variations/imagenet1k-b0-feature-vector/versions/2?tfhub-redirect=true) you can find an example on how to use your EfficientNet V2 (for ImageNet1k) model. The example seems to be almost exactly what your are trying to do.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub

num_classes = 4
m = tf.keras.Sequential(
    [
        hub.KerasLayer(
            r"https://www.kaggle.com/models/google/efficientnet-v2/frameworks"
            r"/TensorFlow2/variations/imagenet1k-b0-feature-vector/versions/2",
            trainable=False,
        ),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation="softmax"),
    ]
)
m.build([None, 224, 224, 3])
```

the code above works on my PC. Remember to: `pip install --upgrade tensorflow-hub`.